# Can versioning or workflow be enabled on a PXM Project in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-pxm

I am using Sitecore Print Experience Manager (PXM)--formerly known as Adaptive Print Studio (APS)--to automate some of the functions of our print shop. One of the features I'd like to enable is the use of versioning and/or workflow on PXM Projects and their sub-items.

Right now, if I associate a workflow with a PXM Project item (e.g. a P_TextFrame), it is not engaged if I make a change in InDesign even if the item is in a final workflow state. The version number stays the same and the item is modified directly.

Is it possible to enable versioning or workflow on PXM Project items?

Comment: You've most likely confirmed this, but have you tried with an non-administrator account? Locking / versioning / workflow are somewhat bypassed when an Sitecore Admin

Comment: I hadn't before, but I did after your suggestion and using InDesign with a non-administrator account does not cause the item to go through workflow or create a new version. It still just edits the approved version.